# How to create a dotted line consisting of circles in css?

Tags: html, css, layout

[image: Example IMG]

It is necessary to create a discontinuous line consisting of circles with a diameter of 4px. And the distance between the circles should be 8px. I can't get the desired result in CSS, please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

radial-gradient can do it:

```css
.line {
  height: 6px; /* diametre */
  background: 
    radial-gradient(circle closest-side, blue 90%, #0000) 
     0/14px 100%; /* 14px = 6px + 8px */
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

Comment: Used big values for the demo but you can easily update

Comment: Thank you, this is the most appropriate solution. And you were the first to give such an answer. Please tell me how to remove the indentation on the left of the dotted line?

Comment: @Lekeer replace the `0` with `-4px` to have `-4px/14px 100%`

Answer (score -2):

**One approach could be like:**

CSS like this:

```
.dot {
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px
}
```

And the HTML body would be like:

```
<body>

<div #dots style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>

</body>
```

Result:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .dot {
      height: 8px;
      width: 8px;
      background-color: #bbb;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div #dots style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution is the first thing that comes to mind. But I would like to avoid a large number of html elements.

Comment: Check the first approach that i added now if you want! but thanks for your response

Comment: why are you copying my answer ?

Comment: I doubt that you received the downvotes for copying an answer. YOu received it because it is upmost impracticable. Also, it only adds a fixed amount that does not fill out the screen or prevent an overflow. You could use an insanely high amount and use overflow hidden which still is impracticable as it puts unnecessary load on the browser and server. All together it misses a practical solution and simplicity.

Comment: No problem then!